# How to set [NonAction] attribute on some actions of ASP.NET Core 5 Web API in startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I need to add `[NonAction]` or `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` attribute on some actions of my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API in startup by external json file, or example list of action names.

```
List<string> ActionNames = new()
                           {
                               "GetLastName",
                               "GetName",
                               "GetAge"
                           };

// I need to add [NonAction] on these actions in startup
```

Comment: What's your goal after setting it to `[NonAction]`?

Answer (score 1):

> How to set [NonAction] attribute on some actions of ASP.NET Core 5 Web
> API in startup

If you look into the details of `[NonAction]` attribute it has derived from `NonActionAttribute` class which is a type of `Sealed` as you can see below:

[image]

Furthermore, In `ControllerActionDescriptor` we have the property  called `CustomAttributes` which derived from `MethodInfo` class and `CustomAttributes` only allow to `get` not `set` so we cannot dynamically set the `CustomAttributes` on controller. As you can see below:

[image]

Therefore, we cannot set the `CustomAttributes` on controller , as it doesn't allow.